# Seg fault in a custom C Shell

Tags: c, shell, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a C shell in a Unix command environment. Thus far, everything is working up to par, however the following command(s) will cause my code to execute correctly, but terminate with a seg fault

```
1. ls | ls | ls
2. ls -al | ls -al > output.txt
```

Bottom line: I believe the segmentation fault is coming from the lines between "XXXX Starts here" and "XXXX Ends here". I also believe it has something to do with the getchar test in the first while loop, although I may be mistaken. If you compile and run this code, you will see upon entering "ls -al | ls -al > output.txt" that everything will execute, followed by shhh> AAAAA being printed, followed by the seg fault. Can anyone confirm or deny my initial observation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

main()
{
   char *path, *argv[20], buf[80], n, *p;
   int m, status, inword, continu;
   int inFlag, outFlag, bgFlag, k, count, j, pipes, pid, aCount, dirCount,
      hCount;
   int r_tube[2], l_tube[2];
   char *hist;
   char *h1[20] = { 0 };
   aCount = 0;
   dirCount = 0;

   while (1)
   {
      inword = 0;
      p = buf;
      m = 0;
      continu = 0;
      inFlag = outFlag = bgFlag = k = count = j = pipes = pid = 0;
      hCount = 0;
      int loc[20] = { 0 };
      char currD[50];

      printf("\nshhh> ");

      while ((n = getchar()) != '\n' || continu)   //XXXXXXXXX Starts here
      {
         if (n == ' ')
         {
            if (inword)
            {
               inword = 0;
               *p++ = 0;
            }
         }
         else if (n == '\n')
            continu = 0;
         else if (n == '\\' && !inword)
            continu = 1;
         else
         {
            if (!inword)
            {
               inword = 1;
               argv[m++] = p;
               *p++ = n;
            }
            else
               *p++ = n;
         }
      }                                    //XXXXXXXX Ends here

      *p++ = 0;
      argv[m] = 0;

      getcwd(currD, 50);

      while (argv[k] != 0)
      {                         //stores all entered commands into history array
         h1[aCount] = strdup(argv[k]);
         aCount++;
         k++;
      }
      k = 0;

      if ((strcmp(argv[0], "history") == 0) ||
         (strcmp(argv[0], "History") == 0))
      {                         //tests to see if history is asked for
         printf("History: \n");
         for (k = 0; k < aCount; k++)
            printf("%s\n", h1[k]);
      }


      if (strcmp(argv[0], "cd") == 0)
      {                         //tests to see if CD is needed
         if (strcmp(argv[1], "..") == 0)
            chdir(currD);
         else
         {
            while (argv[dirCount] != 0)
            {
               getcwd(currD, 50);
               chdir(argv[dirCount]);
               dirCount++;
            }
         }
      }

      char *outFile = NULL;
      char *inFile = NULL;
      loc[0] = 0;

      while (argv[count] != 0)
      {  //while loop sets the flags for input redirection, 
         // output redirection, background operator, and piping
         if (strcmp(argv[count], "<") == 0)
         {
            inFile = strdup(argv[count + 1]);
            argv[count] = argv[count + 1] = 0;
            inFlag = 1;
         }
         else if (strcmp(argv[count], ">") == 0)
         {
            outFile = strdup(argv[count + 1]);
            argv[count] = argv[count + 1] = 0;
            outFlag = 1;
         }
         else if (strcmp(argv[count], "&") == 0)
         {
            argv[count] = 0;
            bgFlag = 1;
         }
         else if (strcmp(argv[count], "|") == 0)
         {
            argv[count] = 0;
            loc[pipes + 1] = count + 1;
            pipes++;
            printf("LOC0: %d ", loc[0]);
            printf("LOC1: %d ", loc[1]);
            printf("LOC2: %d ", loc[2]);
            printf("DONE WITH IF\n");
         }
         else
            loc[count] = count;

         count++;
      }

      for (k = 0; k <= pipes; k++)
      {                         //actual execution of commands
         printf("IN FOR\n");
         if (k < pipes)
         {
            pipe(r_tube);
            j++;
         }

         pid = fork();          //fork child every time to exec

         if (pid > 0)
         {
            if (j > 0)
            {
               close(l_tube[0]);
               close(l_tube[1]);
            }
            l_tube[0] = r_tube[0];
            l_tube[1] = r_tube[1];
         }
         else if (pid == 0)
         {
            if ((k == 0) && (inFlag == 1))
            {
               int n = open(inFile, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);
               if (n == -1)
               {
                  printf("Couldn't open inFile!\n");
                  exit(1);
               }
               close(0);
               dup(n);
               close(n);
            }
            else if ((k == pipes) && (outFlag == 1))
            {
               int out = open(outFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
               if (out < 0)
               {
                  printf("Could'nt open outFile!\n");
                  exit(1);
               }
               close(1);
               dup(out);
               close(out);
            }
            printf("K: %d ", k);
            printf("PIPES: %d ", pipes);
            printf("PID: %d\n", pid);
            execvp(argv[loc[k]], &argv[loc[k]]);
         }
         printf("ONE\n");
         if (bgFlag == 0)
            wait(NULL);
      }
      printf("TWO\n");
      if (strcmp(argv[0], "quit") == 0)
         exit(0);               //tests for exit/quit to end program
      if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
         exit(0);
      printf("THREE\n");
      for (k = 0; k < 20; k++)  //reset all of argv to NULL
         argv[k] = 0;
      printf("FOUR\n");

      wait(&status);
   }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: learn to use a debugger, debug, and isolate the problem.

Comment: You need to narrow down your question, so that it would be a useful question for others as well as you

Comment: Do you really expect from us that we read the whole code without a hint from you?

Comment: I have remarked my code with where I believe the error is coming from. That portion of the code was supplied by the teacher, so I'm confused on how to trace through it. The portion of the code is from "XXXXXStarts here" to "XXXXXEnds here"

Comment: Compile your code with warnings enabled. If you're using gcc, try `gcc -O3 -Wall -Wextra`. Fix all the problems diagnosed by the compiler *before* you start worrying about whether the program works. In particular, you're missing at least two `#include` directives.

Comment: After running that code, the only warnings I'm receiving deal with the implicit declaration of my strdup and strcmp calls, which (from my understanding) I can ignore, due to the fact that I'm using argv[xx] as the parameter for the comparison. There is no warning for #include directives.

Comment: One problem is that `n` is a `char`, not an `int`, and the code does not look for EOF.  So, when I indicated EOF, I got a crash.

Comment: With changes to handle EOF, I've run the code on Mac OS X 10.7.5 with GCC 4.7.1 (and it compiled pretty clean, though I had to add `<string.h>` to get `strdup()` declared).  The code seems to work for me; it ran essentially cleanly under `valgrind`, too.  One change I made was moving a number of variable declarations inside the `while (1)` loop, so that they are initialized on each iteration.  That was more because I'm not keen on variables at a bigger scope than necessary than for any other reason, but maybe you should look at what gets initialized. _[continued]_

Comment: _[continuation]_  I see '`ls | ls | ls`' produce three copies of the output, which is not what I'd expect.  The `ls` command normally ignores its standard input, so in a normal shell, you'd only see one copy of the output from three invocations of `ls` piped together.  There must be a bug somewhere, therefore, in your handling of pipes.  But I've not gotten the code to crash since I deal with EOF cleanly (and I see that you're supposed to type `quit` or `exit`, but old habits die hard, and you should deal with EOF anyway, even if the professor provided that section of the code).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deal with segmentation faults is to analyze stack trace saved into coredump produced by kernel. Most of the distributions have coredump saving disabled, so there is how it can be enabled

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Proc file system has several files to configure corudump production. The most important is [core pattern](http://linux.die.net/man/5/core) `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`, which specify coredump name and optionally post-process commands.

When process receives segmentation fault signal, kernel will save it's state in a coredump file, which can be later inspected with [dgb](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gdb):

```
gdb -c core ./binary_which_produced_the_core
bt
```

this will print you a back trace of what the program was doing when segmentation fault has happened.

For example, for your program

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  main () at main.c:58
58                 *p++ = n;
(gdb) bt
#0  main () at main.c:58
(gdb)
```

note, I had to add missing headers, so line number is +2.

And please, use `-Wall -Wextra` compiler options to report all warning and always fix them. For example, you have l_tube array uninitialized.